# How to escape HTML or AMPscript in AMPscript variables?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, commerce-cloud, xss

I was wondering what happens when a customer is putting html or scripts in his profile attributes on Commerce Cloud and he orders something and we send out an order confirmation email with those attributes in the email. How can we avoid rendering that HTML/Script and just paste it as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape AmpScript in variables unless you explicitly ask the platform to render it by wrapping it in [TreatAsContent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm). Example:

```
%%[ SET @Firstname = "%%=add(2,2)=%%" ]%%
```

We can reference it using:

```
%%=v(@Firstname)=%%
```

Outputting:
*%%=add(2,2)=%%*

Or We can reference it:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(@Firstname)=%%
```

Outputting:
*4*

For HTML, you can use RegexMatch, which Adam Spriggs illustrates [in his blog](https://sprignaturemoves.com/regex-in-ampscript/). Using **<[^>]*>** as your [matching pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Lcx35S/1), will find all the HTML tags, which you can then use [Replace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/Replace.htm) function to strip out.

However, for both AmpScript and HTML, I will recommend you to do validation on input, and not on output - as this will improve your data quality. Following the approach I have described is doable, but only fix the symptoms - not the core of the problem.

Comment: And what about HTML? Because we currently have the issue where escaped HTML is passed through XML (e.g., <b>Lukas Lunow</b>) but when printing this name in the email it is in bold.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Feels like an impossible job though, as there is also SQL, SSJS, etc. Commerce Cloud escapes them by default, wish MC did the same.

Comment: This is why I suggest doing validation on the form, when profile attributes are created in Commerce Cloud. This will solve this across all these aspects you mention

Comment: @user3485470 - please accept/upvote my answer if it has been helpful

Comment: Trying to sanitize data on input will only lead to security holes and frustration. You're best off making sure your output is always properly escaped for whichever platform that you're outputting into (ie - html, mobile, sql, etc.).